# FUNCAO JAVA SCRIPT VALIDACAO CPF

Tags: javascript

Olá.

Como faço para inserir os pontos e hífen no CPF e também restringir a quantidade de dígitos? Obrigado!

```
function validaCPF(cpf)
  {
    var numeros, digitos, soma, i, resultado, digitos_iguais;
    digitos_iguais = 1;
    if (cpf.length < 11)
          return false;
    for (i = 0; i < cpf.length - 1; i++)
          if (cpf.charAt(i) != cpf.charAt(i + 1))
                {
                digitos_iguais = 0;
                break;
                }
    if (!digitos_iguais)
          {
          numeros = cpf.substring(0,9);
          digitos = cpf.substring(9);
          soma = 0;
          for (i = 10; i > 1; i--)
                soma += numeros.charAt(10 - i) * i;
          resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
          if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0))
                return false;
          numeros = cpf.substring(0,10);
          soma = 0;
          for (i = 11; i > 1; i--)
                soma += numeros.charAt(11 - i) * i;
          resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
          if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1))
                return false;
          return true;
          }
    else
        return false;
  }
```

Comment: essa função apenas diz se o cpf é válido ou não, você quer fazer uma função que retorne o cpf formatado caso ele seja válido? é isto?

Comment: Mano, seguinte, o que vc quer se chama Mascara e não validação

Use esse plugin
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

$("SEUIDENTIFICADOR").mask('999.999.999-99');

sucesso!

Comment: Ok! Obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queira formatar o CPF válido, você pode aproveitar esta função que você criou, e simplesmente fazer algo do tipo:

Função para reescrever o valor no formato desejado:

```
function format(value, pattern) {
    var i = 0,
        v = value.toString();
    return pattern.replace(/#/g, _ => v[i++]);
}
```

Função que formata:

```
function formatCpf(cpf) {
    let cpfValido = validaCPF(cpf)
    if(cpfValido) return format(cpf, '###.###.###-##');
    return cpf;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Matheus Ribeiro.

Comment: por favor, se minha resposta ter lhe ajudado, marque como a resposta